# v-model no component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, componentes, component

Estou tentando usar o v-model dentro de um componente porém não funciona.

Código main.js, que terá a informaçõa usada no v-model:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {fields: {name: 'Vittar', age: 24}}
})
```

Código do meu componente:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.component('dynamic-field', {
  props: ['value'],
  template: '<input type="text" :value="value" v-model="value">',   
})
```

No caso eu passaria a propriedade fields.name na prop value do meu input e usaria essa mesma prop no v-model como aparece no código do componente:

```
props: ['value'],
template: '<input type="text" :value="value" v-model="value">',
```

HTML:

```
<dynamic-field :value="fields.name"></dynamic-field>
```

Porém nao funciona, dá o seguinte erro:
*`[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "value"`*

Comment: Encontrei uma solução explicativa no stackoverflow em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915436/vuejs-update-parent-data-from-child-component